# `\show` for macro arguments

Tags: macros, package-writing, debugging

For debugging purposes, I want to write to the log what is actually passed to a macro as argument. A naive `\newcommand\test[1]{\show#1}` obviously doesn't do the job. So how can I printout a list of all tokens `#1` is replaced by, without any further expansion performed?

My goal is the following: the macro `\test` is invoked by another macro which I have no insight into without much ado. I want to understand what that macro passes to `\test`; in this particular case, whether `#1` contains any formatting commands.

Comment: `\typeout{#1}`, perhaps.

Comment: @egreg I see, fully expanded was not precisely the right thing to ask. This would not help me at all. Please see my edited question.

Comment: Perhaps `\newcommand\test[1]{\typeout{\unexpanded{#1}}}` ? Or `\newcommand\test[1]{\def\temp{#1}\typeout{\meaning\temp}}` ? Or `\newcommand\test[1]{\def\temp{#1}\show\temp}` ?

Comment: @egreg Thanks, that's it.

Comment: I use `\showtokens{#1}` or, for more detailed info, `\tl_analysis_show:n {#1}` (the latter requires `expl3` and `\ExplSyntaxOn`).